# my dpkg seems to be corrupt or broken

Tags: dpkg, apport, tomcat7

Few weeks ago, I had deleted my `dpkg` folder by mistake (`sudo rm -f "something that had dpkg directory"`)

After few panic attacks, I followed Ask Ubuntu and restored `dpkg` (or at least I thought I did), but later, few issues started creeping. For example:

1. my microphone is not working and the package `pavucontrol` is not installing
2. my `tomcat7` broke and re-installation was failing

and all of these were failing with following output..

```
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service runmbbservice and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and dns-clean if started
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
  Package apport is not configured yet.
 apport-gtk depends on procps; however:
  Package procps is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
 apport
 apport-gtk
```

so can anyone please help me?

here is the output of some key commands I know you will ask

```
parag@pkul3003:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ uname -a
Linux pkul3003 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
parag@pkul3003:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

parag@pkul3003:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ cat /etc/insserv.conf
$local_fs   +umountfs
$network    +networking
$named      +named +dnsmasq +lwresd +bind9 +unbound $network
$remote_fs  $local_fs +umountnfs +sendsigs
$syslog     +rsyslog +sysklogd +syslog-ng +dsyslog +inetutils-syslogd
$time       +hwclock
<interactive>   glibc udev console-screen keymap keyboard-setup console-setup cryptdisks cryptdisks-early checkfs-loop
```

Comment: Check in terminal `history | grep sudo` to find the exact command you used

Comment: Read the first four lines of error *carefully*, then locate those services in /etc/init.d and edit the LSB headers to eliminate the loops.